# Asterisk server firewall script allows 2-way audio from incoming calls, but not on outgoing?

Tags: networking, firewall, iptables, voip, asterisk

I'm running an Asterisk PBX on a virtual machine directly connected to the Internet and I really want to prevent script kiddies, l33t h4x0rz and actual hackers access to my server. The basic way I protect my calling-bill now is by using 32 character passwords, but I would much rather have a way to protect

The firewall script I'm currently using is stated below, however, without the established connection firewall rule (mentioned rule #1), I cannot receive incoming audio from the target during outgoing calls:

```
#!/bin/bash

# first, clean up!
iptables -F
iptables -X
iptables -t nat -F
iptables -t nat -X
iptables -t mangle -F
iptables -t mangle -X
iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P FORWARD DROP # we're not a router
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT

# don't allow invalid connections
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state INVALID -j DROP

# always allow connections that are already set up (MENTIONED RULE #1)
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

# always accept ICMP
iptables -A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT

# always accept traffic on these ports
#iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT

# always allow DNS traffic
iptables -A INPUT -p udp --sport 53 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT

# allow return traffic to the PBX
iptables -A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 50000:65536 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 10000:20000 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p udp --destination-port 5060:5061 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --destination-port 5060:5061 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -m multiport -p udp --dports 10000:20000
iptables -A INPUT -m multiport -p tcp --dports 10000:20000

# IP addresses of the office
iptables -A INPUT -s 95.XXX.XXX.XXX/32 -j ACCEPT

# accept everything from the trunk IP's
iptables -A INPUT -s 195.XXX.XXX.XXX/32 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -s 195.XXX.XXX.XXX/32 -j ACCEPT

# accept everything on localhost
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT

# accept all outgoing traffic
iptables -A OUTPUT -j ACCEPT

# DROP everything else
#iptables -A INPUT -j DROP
```

I would like to know what firewall rule I'm missing for this all to work.. There is so little documentation on which ports (incoming and outgoing) asterisk actually needs.. (return ports included).

Are there any firewall/iptables specialists here that see major problems with this firewall script?

It's so frustrating not being able to find a simple firewall solution that enabled me to have a PBX running somewhere on the Internet which is firewalled in such a way that it can ONLY allows connections from and to the office, the DNS servers and the trunk(s) (and only support SSH (port 22) and ICMP traffic for the outside world).

Hopefully, using this question, we can solve this problem once and for all.

Comment: Why does one port range end in 65536? That may cause an error, since the highest possible port number is 65535. Why do the last two rules under "allow return of traffic to the PBX" not have `-j` statements? Why is "IP addresses of the office" a single IP address -- is there a NAT gateway between the office machines and the Asterisk box? Why do you have a specific output rule for destination port 53, when you already accept all output? Why do you have your main input policy set to ACCEPT, and then end with a "DROP everything else" command -- why not set the input policy to DROP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is full documentation about ports availible. It is not clear why you think it not availble.

Asterisk use port depend of technology/channel type used

For sip protocol asterisk use port described in sip.conf(default 5060) and for rtp data use ports described in rtp.conf(default 10000-20000). Usually sip use only udp port. TCP-sip can also use tcp port.

If you use asterisk after firewall/NAT(not white ip), you also have inform asterisk about external ip address. For more info see sip.conf.sample or manuals in internet.

Comment: Well, I knew those (udp 5060 and 10000-20000 (specified it manually)), however, I do not want to open them to the Internet, just to my office IP.. but whenever I do that, I'm running into problems such as 2-way audio that isn't working..

Comment: There are no way say what is wrong. Check nat settings/sip debug.

Comment: I will have another look.. thanks for the tips so far.